# Rails: Upgrading the rails version from 5.0 to 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

We're trying to upgrade Rails from 5.0.0.1 to the latest 5.2 in a huge application, the issue is that the change to the 5.2 breaks most tests because of the way callbacks work in 5.0 vs 5.2.

After Rails 4.x release, some changes were made on callbacks to split update on the model before and after writing data to the database. We had to be careful to use the correct helpers:

```
# Rails 5.0
after_save   :update_customer_details!,  if: :status_changed?
after_commit :create_new_email_address!, if: -> { previous_changes[:email] }
```

But with Rails 5.1, the code above becomes :

```
# Rails 5.1
after_save   :update_customer_details!,  if: :saved_changes_to_status?
after_commit :create_new_email_address!, if: :saved_changes_to_email?
```

The issue is that the codebase is so huge and callbacks are used everywhere that changing regex or line by line simply does not solve the issue.

Do you know of any way to upgrade to 5.2.X and still use the old behaviour ?

Comment: Even if keeping old behaviour was an option, what are you going to do next? 5.2 is a pretty old version already, you need to upgrade eventually.

Comment: I have gone through upgrading about 3 big apps myself.   You end up shooting yourself in the foot trying to keep the old syntax.  Just bite the bullet and make the changes and you will be glad you did